# checking and summing a value in a delimitted list

Tags: vba, excel

I am checking for a value in Column D and populating this as a summary list in column E. I currently do not have the total in Column F which would be a summed up value from column C as shown below in the test data.

Test Data

```
Sheet Name: Transactions Expected Result
Column A Column B Column C Column D    Column E       Column F
ID         Name      Amount   BID      BIDSummary    Total Amount
123        John        100    0,111       111            400
456        Bill        200    122,0       122            200
789        Tony        300    0,111
```

[image]

Comment: You already have Column E?

Comment: Yes I am looking to now get column F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(FIND("," & E2 & "," , "," & $D$2:$D$4 & ",")))*($C$2:$C$4))
```

Based on your photo that is different than your test data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(FIND(";" & E2 & ";" , ";" & $D$2:$D$4 & ";")))*($C$2:$C$4))
```

The `"," & ... & ","` on both the search and criterion make it so `11` does not return on `112` or `111`, or `0` is found in `101` or `110`

[image]

---

If your codes are always three digits then you can use a wild card SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"*" & E2 & "*")
```

But this will find partial matches.  `0` would be found in `101` and `110` and could return false positives.

Comment: Hi, in cell F2 I am getting 0 when using this formula.

Comment: I would prefer to use vba as that's what I have used throughout if possible

Comment: please review the image I have just attached showing the 0 in F2.

Comment: Well 1) your test data shows `,` as the deliniator.  Change the `","` to `";"`.  2) if you want vba you will need to show what you have tried

Comment: I am going to just use the formula thanks for your help I will accept your answer